# Displaying two images in single column on datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

how can i create a column that can display 2 images in one column on datagridview?

i tried to create 2 datagridviewimagecolumn (for the different images)
and if it the cell in it contains the same image path. 
the image will match depending on the path on the cell. 
this must combine in one column (as shown on the figure below)

for example.

here i will create 2 datagridimagecolumn

```
DataGridViewImageColumn img1 - new DataGridViewImageColumn();
Image Simg1 = Image.FromFile (C:\Desktop\Green.jpg);
img1.Image = Simg1;
dgv.Columns.Add(img1); //it will display on the datagridview

DataGridViewImageColumn img2 - new DataGridViewImageColumn();
    Image Simg2 = Image.FromFile (C:\Desktop\Red.jpg);
    img2.Image = Simg1;
    dgv.Columns.Add(img2);
```

if the generated column from the sql server looks like this

column1
--------- 
c:\Desktop\Greeen.jpg
c:\Desktop\Green.jpg
c:\Desktop\Red.jpg
c:\Desktop\Green.jpg

how will i do this one.
the green path will display green image. 
and the red path will contain red image.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand well your question but I think you can work around creating an Image that is the tiling of the 2 images and print it inside your column.

you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6383123/merge-two-images-to-create-a-single-image-in-c-net) or [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CompositingTwoImagesIntoOneFromTheASPNETServerSide.aspx) how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to write your own merged cell class implementing onpaint event. You can see an example of it's being done [here](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?415930-DataGridView-Merging-Cells).