# 3D image in c# using different images

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine

I've different angle 2D images(images of one particular object), I want to merge all that three images and create one 3D Image.

How can I do that in Unity 3D?

Comment: any code you have tried ? please post your code with your question  !

Comment: @SunilKumar, I don't know how to do that, I've tried to search but didn't got any solution

Comment: refer these links : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12789/Merging-Images-in-NET and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6383123/merge-two-images-to-create-a-single-image-in-c-net

Comment: @SunilKumar, merging two image will be not generate 3D image

Comment: after merging then convert that image into 3D view. Refer this link for convert 2D image into 3D view: http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_general/graphics/article.php/c11375/Creating-an-Interactive-3D-World-in-CNET.htm

Comment: 3d image? 3d view? are you talking to make a 3d object from a picture only with code?

Comment: @joreldraw Yes exactly, i want to make app, in which user can marge 3 different images of single object and create 3D image

Answer (score 7):

The process you're looking for is called [Photogrammetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photogrammetry). To get good quality models, you'll want more than 3 images. This process is very CPU intensive and takes a long time, you won't want this built into your Unity3D Game/App. You'll want to generate the models with external tools, then import them.

- If you actually are looking for a C# way to do this, I only know of one opensource library working on this. [Epicycle.Photogrammetry-cs](https://github.com/open-epicycle/Epicycle.Photogrammetry-cs).
- If you want to manage the whole process of the conversion, check out this [tutorial](http://wedidstuff.heavyimage.com/index.php/2013/07/12/open-source-photogrammetry-workflow/) using only open source software.
- This YouTube [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D6eqW6yk50k) is easy to follow (I've done it myself), and also uses only free software.
- If you're looking for a more polished, less technical solution, try [ReMake](https://remake.autodesk.com/about) by Autodesk
- If you're looking for a completely hands off process, try [123D Catch](http://www.123dapp.com/catch) by Autodesk