# Create one image from various image files

Tags: c#, .net, image, graphics, drawing

I need to make up an image from various other image files and then save that generated image. So for example image 1 needs to be positioned at x and y co-ordinate of 0,0 then the next file goes to 150,0 and so on

Is the best approach to use Graphics.DrawImage?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/465172/merging-two-images-in-c-net/465195#465195):

This will add an image to another:

```
using (Graphics grfx = Graphics.FromImage(image))
{
grfx.DrawImage(newImage, x, y)
}
```