# Merge two images for "fade" transition with changing opacity? (C#/PNG)

Tags: c#, graphics, fade

First of all, I'd like to suggest that it is not a duplicate of [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/465172/merging-two-images-in-c-net) question. At least that's my opinion :)

What I want to achieve is a series of frames to "fade" animation.

I choose two PNG files (let' say they are the same size), for example:

- [Picture 1](http://wronx.net/misc/so/pic1.png)
- [Picture 2](http://wronx.net/misc/so/pic2.png)

I want to "simulate" merging them like layers in graphic editor. I put Pic1 on the top with opacity 255, Pic2 below with opacity 0, so at first I see only Pic1. Then I change their opacity, like this:

- [Pic1-200, Pic2-150](http://wronx.net/misc/so/200_150.png)
- [Pic1-150, Pic2-200](http://wronx.net/misc/so/150_200.png)
- [Pic1-100, Pic2-230](http://wronx.net/misc/so/100_230.png)

Is there any simple way for it?

Comment: No code, no cookie! What have you tried so far?

Comment: Are we talking WPF? Win Forms? Silverlight?

Comment: Sorry, WinForms. Here's the cookie: http://wronx.net/misc/so/fade.txt - I found a little different example and managed to change it myself. Not sure, if it is mathematically correct, but it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a winforms app this can be done pretty easily. Create a user control with a few properties:

```
public Image FromImage { get; set; }
public Image ToImage { get; set; }

private float opacity = 1;
```

Now override OnPaint

```
 protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (FromImage != null && ToImage != null)
        {
            ColorMatrix matrix1 = new ColorMatrix();
            matrix1.Matrix33 = opacity;
            ImageAttributes attributes1 = new ImageAttributes();
            attributes1.SetColorMatrix(matrix1, ColorMatrixFlag.Default, ColorAdjustType.Bitmap);


            ColorMatrix matrix2 = new ColorMatrix();
            matrix2.Matrix33 = 1 - opacity;
            ImageAttributes attributes2 = new ImageAttributes();
            attributes2.SetColorMatrix(matrix2, ColorMatrixFlag.Default, ColorAdjustType.Bitmap);

            e.Graphics.DrawImage(FromImage, new Rectangle(0, 0, this.Width, this.Height), 0, 0, this.Width,
                                 this.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, attributes1);
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(ToImage, new Rectangle(0, 0, this.Width, this.Height), 0, 0, this.Width,
                                 this.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, attributes2);
        }
        base.OnPaint(e);
    }
```

Now drop a timer onto the control, set its to enabled with an elapsed time of something like 100ms. Handle the tick event:

```
private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(opacity == 0)
        {
            this.timer.Stop();
            return;
        }

        this.opacity -= 0.01f;
        this.Invalidate();
    }
```

et voila. However, there's one thing to be aware of. This makes quite a flickery transition, which can be alieviated somewhat with this line in the control's constructor:

```
this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint,true);
```

---

Update based on Edit: You could turn this into a utility that takes 2 images and, using much the same code, outputs each step to a new image. Somthing like:

```
public class ImageUtility
{
    private Image image1;
    private Image image2;

    public ImageUtility(Image image1, Image image2)
    {
        this.image1 = image1;
        this.image2 = image2;
    }

    public void SaveTransitions(int numSteps, string outDir)
    {
        var opacityChange = 1.0f/(float) numSteps;

        for(float opacity = 1,i=0;opacity>0;opacity-=opacityChange,i++)
        {
            using(var image = new Bitmap(image1.Width,image2.Width))
            {
                Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(image);
                ColorMatrix matrix1 = new ColorMatrix();
                matrix1.Matrix33 = opacity;
                ImageAttributes attributes1 = new ImageAttributes();
                attributes1.SetColorMatrix(matrix1, ColorMatrixFlag.Default, ColorAdjustType.Bitmap);


                ColorMatrix matrix2 = new ColorMatrix();
                matrix2.Matrix33 = 1 - opacity;
                ImageAttributes attributes2 = new ImageAttributes();
                attributes2.SetColorMatrix(matrix2, ColorMatrixFlag.Default, ColorAdjustType.Bitmap);

                g.DrawImage(image1, new Rectangle(0, 0, image1.Width, image1.Height), 0, 0, image1.Width,
                                     image1.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, attributes1);
                g.DrawImage(image2, new Rectangle(0, 0, image2.Width, image2.Height), 0, 0, image2.Width,
                                     image2.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, attributes2);

                image.Save(Path.Combine(outDir,"Image" + i + ".png"),ImageFormat.Png);
            }
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```
ImageUtility util = new ImageUtility(Image.FromFile(@"C:\path\pic1.png"), Image.FromFile(@"C:\path\pic2.png"));
util.SaveTransitions(100, @"C:\path\output"); // saves 100 images
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand it - where's the "second" image? I want to fade one image to another and save every "frame" of the animation.

Comment: @WRonX - see update. Pretty easy to turn the same code to a util that saves each transition out to disk.

Comment: I'll check it, but I suppose it can be the answer. Thank you! My solution (in comments to question) fails at transparent PNGs, so I'll check yours. I assume if I need a preview, I can just cast and assign, I mean pictureBox1.Image=(Image)image; ??

Comment: You *suppose* it can be the answer? Dont sound too enthusiastic or anything.

Comment: Maybe it sounded that way, because: 1. My English isn't good. 2. I'm usually not that good at C# to know if it is what I meant only by reading the code and I can't check it now (different place, different machine). Sorry, if it offended you, I didn't mean that way. I *AM* enthusiastic about ending what I started, so once again: thank you very much!

Comment: @WRonX - you're very welcome. I was only being a bit sarcastic with my comment above :)

Answer (score 1):

Using [winforms](/questions/tagged/winforms) you can use [`Graphics.DrawImage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142042.aspx), using the overload that takes an [`ImageAttributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.imageattributes.aspx) parameter. That class can specify manipulation to the colour (**and alpha**) values.

The example on the `ImageAttributes` page is nearly what you want. Just draw the original and transformed one in the same place, and change the colour matrix to only change the alpha level.