# Save picturebox with labels in it as JPEG in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, picturebox

I'm new to C# and Windows Forms and I would like to save a `PictureBox` with labels in it in JPEG format.

This is my code so far:

```
SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
sfd.Filter = "JPG(*.JPG)|*.jpg";  
if(sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    pictureBox1.Image.Save(sfd.FileName, 
System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```

There are labels in the picturebox, but they are not saved as well. Do you have any idea?

Comment: I just dragged them with the mouse in the picturebox, I can't really tell the difference ^^

Comment: And how do I save the picturebox with the labels on top as one image?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Save Image in PictureBox with overlapping Controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18740077/save-image-in-picturebox-with-overlapping-controls)

Comment: Add controls to the `PictureBox`, then `DrawToBitmap` will draw those controls and the `Image` of the `PictureBox` on target bitmap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most simple option is adding those labels to `PictureBox` control. Then using [`DrawToBitmap`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.drawtobitmap(v=vs.110).aspx) you can draw those labels and the image to a bitmap:

```
var bm = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
pictureBox1.DrawToBitmap(bm, new Rectangle(0,0,pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height));
```

Then save the bitmap in any format which you need.

***Note 1***: Don't forget to dispose the bitmap if you don't need it after saving.

***Note 2***: `DrawBitmap` draws the labels just if you add them to the `Controls` collection of the `PictureBox`:

```
var label1 = new Label() { 
    Text = "Some Text",
    BackColor = Color.Transparent,
    Location = new Point(10, 10)
};
pictureBox1.Controls.Add(label1);
```

Comment: Thank, that worked perfectly! When I save the bitmap in jpeg format with my previous code above, the picture is cut off.

Comment: Do you have any idea why the image is cut off when saving it?^^ When I move it to the center of the form it gets more visible

Comment: I did a correction: `pictureBox1.DrawToBitmap(bm, new Rectangle(0,0,pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height));`.